# User Profile auto created on all PCs in AD

Tags: active-directory, user-profile, profile

For some reason a user profile has been created on every PC on Windows Server 2003 Domain. The client machines are XP. The profile was created on all machines at the same time.

Any ideas whats happened?

Comment: Is this causing you a specific issue? Is the account a domain account or local account?

Answer (score 3):

Likely the user who created the workstation image forgot to remove their profile before sysprepping. This is even more likely the case since the time it was created is the exact same on all machines.

Answer (score 2):

You may have a scheduled task set to run as that user on all the machines at the same time.

The task could have been set up by Group Policy perhaps?

Comment: Hi Phil, thanks for the reply.. Ill start going though the GPOs to see what i can find..

Comment: well Ive ran a group policy modelling on a user/pc who has the profile added to there machine.. and i cant see any reference to the account in the report... (Have i over simplified my search?) ive not used GPO in years. so bit rusty..